# Extract Build Identifier from Crash Report?

Tags: xcode, crash-reports

[Technical Q&A QA1765 : How to Match a Crash Report to a Build](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1765/_index.html) explains how to "Find the Build Identifier in a Crash Report" using `grep`.

```
$ grep -A=1 "Binary Images:" Example.crash
Binary Images:
   0xb6000 - 0xb7fff +Example armv7 <270a9b9d7a333a4a9f1aaf8186f81394> /var/mobile/Applications/28D4F177-D312-4D3B-A76C-C2ACB4CB7DAD/Example.app/Example
```

But, what's the best way to extract just the build identifier: `270a9b9d7a333a4a9f1aaf8186f81394`?

Answer (score 0):

The Technical Q&A that you linked to states:

> The first line in the "Binary Images:" section of a crash report includes the build identifier, inside <>.

So, I would go with something like:

```
grep -A 1 "Binary Images:" Example.crash | sed -n 's/.*<\([a-z0-9]\{32\}\)>.*/\1/p'
```

Comment: What kind of shenanigans is this, answering your own question within less than a minute? Is this one of these "I wanted to post and answer a reference question that might help somebody else" kind of deals?

Comment: Sure. I figured out an answer to the question as I was asking it. Note: It's not "my own question." I don't "own" this question. It's just a question I had. There's a subtle but important difference, as [Eckhart Tolle](http://www.eckharttolle.com) explains in his books. :) Others may also have the same question. May *this* answer (Notice, it's not *my* answer.) serve them.